# How to run script with elevated privilege on windows but only the first time when i run it

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i already wrote a program that asks for admin privileges, but the problem is the admin have to grant permission every time it runs

so is there anyway that the program stays on admin privilege without asking for permission everytime

*code example*

```
from pyuac import main_requires_admin

@main_requires_admin

def main():
    print("Do stuff here that requires being run as an admin.")
    # The window will disappear as soon as the program exits!
    input("Press enter to close the window. >")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I misunderstood your question. After reading it again, I think you are asking how to always run your program with admin permissions, but only request confirmation the first time, right?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that's not the way Admin works in Windows.  It will always ask for confirmation.

Comment: @MarkRansom Then you should ping the OP, not me. I tried posting an answer, but it didn't really address the question, so I deleted it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the questioner automatically gets pinged when you leave a comment on their question.

Comment: @MarkRansom so i cant run without one time confirmation? for example if i want to access "Program Files" i have to ask for admin permission everytime

Comment: perhaps you could create a launcher: [how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/](https://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/)